# sumar ciertas partes de una lista en python

Tags: python

En este momento estoy intentando hacer algunos análisis de datos sin `pandas` para intentar desarrollar una mejor habilidad en programación, es decir, complicarme la vida. lo que haría muy fácil en `pandas` se me ha vuelto un dolor de cabezas sin utilizar esta librería.

En este caso estoy queriendo sumar ciertas partes de una lista. Esta lista tiene, entre tantas, dos columnas: una que solo son letras y otra un numero cualquiera. lo que quiero es sumar los números que están asociadas a esas letras.

```
lista_a = [a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,c,c,d,d,d...]
lista_b = [23,4,345,32,534,6,323,5,323,...]
```

Es decir, en pandas yo haría el siguiente proceso si lo estuviese utilizando:

```
import pandas as pd 
# convierto  a data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
# corto esas dos columnas
df = df[["lista_a","lista_b"]]
#convierto  a entero
df["lista_b"] = df["lista_b"].astype(int)
# hago la suma de cada registro por letra
df.groupby("Lista_b").sum()

[out]:
          lista_b
Lista_a     
A         37
B         36
C         27
D         23
E         67
```

Para hacerlo sin pandas lo que he hecho es

```
lista_a = [i[0] for i in lista_a]
lista_a2 = set(lista_a)
lista_b = [int(i) for i in lista_b]
l = []
for i in lista_a2:
  c = 0

  for x in lista_a:
    if i == x:
      for n in lista_b:
        c = sum(lista_b)            

  l.append((i, c))
  l = sorted(l)

for i in l:
  print(i[0]+','+str(i[1]))

[out]:

A,34
B,34
C,34
D,34
E,34
```

34 es la suma de todos los números de mi columna real, pero no el resultado de cada uno de los registros por letra. ¿Alguna idea para ver que le falla al código?
Mil gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El código falla por que `c` es la suma de toda tu columna (`lista_b`), dado que haces `c = sum(lista_b)`, cuando debería ser la suma de los valores de `lista_b` para los que el elemento `x` en el mismo índice en `lista_a` cumple con `if i == x`.

Si seguimos tu idea original, el código debería ser algo así:

```
lista_a = ["A", "A","A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"]
lista_b = [23, 4, 345, 32, 534, 6, 323, 5, 323, 13, 17, 19, 23, 7]

lista_a2 = set(lista_a)

l = []
for i in lista_a2:
  c = 0
  for indice, x in enumerate(lista_a):
    if i == x:
        c += lista_b[indice]

  l.append((i, c))
  l.sort()
```

No obstante, esto es muy ineficiente porque iteramos una vez sobre `lista_b` por cada valor distinto de `lista_a`. La clave para hacer esto simple y eficiente es usar un diccionario y `zip` para iterar a la par sobre ambas listas en un solo ciclo:

```
lista_a = ["A", "A","A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"]
lista_b = [23, 4, 345, 32, 534, 6, 323, 5, 323, 13, 17, 19, 23, 7]

res = dict.fromkeys(lista_a, 0)
for a, b in zip(lista_a, lista_b):
   res[a] += b

print(*(f"{key}, {value}" for key, value in res.items()), sep="\n")
```

o usando `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections

res = collections.defaultdict(int)
for a, b in zip(lista_a, lista_b):
   res[a] += b

print(*(f"{key}, {value}" for key, value in res.items()), sep="\n")
```

Ciertamente podemos usar también `itertools.groupby`, pero no me parece ni lo más legible ni simple en este caso.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

res = [(key, sum(g[1] for g in group))
        for key, group in groupby(sorted(zip(lista_a, lista_b)), itemgetter(0))]

print(*(f"{a}, {b}" for a, b in res), sep="\n")
```

Hay que recordar siempre que `itertools.groupby` necesita que los datos estén ordenados adecuadamente en función de la clave de agrupamiento previamente. En este caso ya lo estaban, por lo que `sorted(zip(lista_a, lista_b))` podría quedar como `zip(lista_a, lista_b)` simplemente, pero de no estarlo hay que ordenar o el resultado será incorrecto.

La salida en cualquier caso es:

> A, 404
>   B, 1191
>   C, 30
>   D, 49